# How to invalid syntastic check for .html file with vim

Tags: vim, syntastic

Do you know how to check for invalid syntax in an HTML file? I'm using ember.js with syntastic plugin vim plugin and it is producing warnings that make me confused.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Perhaps some of the HTML code and the warnings that it is producing?

Comment: hi,@jasonlfunk, my code is                                        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.MyView}}
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    {{/view}}
  </script>

Comment: it outputs '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here warnings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That code is invalid because `<script>` is not supposed to contain any other HTML tag.

`:help syntastic` shows how to disable syntax checking for a given filetype:

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map={ 'mode': 'active',
                     \ 'active_filetypes': [],
                     \ 'passive_filetypes': ['html'] }
```